# How did the Community bot update a reference to an incorrect patch number?

Tags: discussion

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/239793/revisions

The community bot fixed grammatical error, which I can understand, but it knew to fix the patch update number from 1.12 to 1.2?  How did it know that?!

Comment: Community owns edits of anonymously suggested edits.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the history (which you linked), the Community user didn't edit this question.

Edits proposed by anonymous users show up as being done by the Community user.

Comment: This and other tasks performed by the Community User are also explained on it's [profile](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: Related: [Who is the community user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) from Meta.SE